# Custom sort strings -- if starting with a specific string, then alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, substring

I would like to sort strings in PHP, and the match should be done foremost on the first letters of a substring, then on the letters of the whole the string.

For example, if someone searches `do`, and the list contains

```
Adolf
Doe
Done
```

the result should be

```
Doe
Done
Adolf
```

Using the regular `sort($array, SORT_STRING)` or things like that does not work, Adolf is sorted before the others.

Does someone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: You can't do it with a simple search. I suggest you create multiple list, for each position of the occurrence you are looking for, then sort these sub-lists.

Comment: @user1603166, your question is slightly ambiguous. From @Roman's example, if the list also included `Odometer` and `Abdomen`, how should it be sorted?

Answer (score 3):

[`usort(array, callback)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) lets you sort based on a callback.

example (something like this, didn't try it)

```
usort($list, function($a, $b) {
   $posa = strpos(tolower($a), 'do');
   $posb = strpos(tolower($b), 'do');
   if($posa != 0 && $posb != 0)return strcmp($a, $b);
   if($posa == 0 && $posb == 0)return strcmp($a, $b);
   if($posa == 0 && $posb != 0)return -1;
   if($posa != 0 && $posb == 0)return 1;
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Ok usort let me sort with a function on my own, but the problem is still that sorting functions give me Adolf before Doe in this case.

Comment: Depending on how many comparisons are made within the `usort()` this can get pretty heavy :)

Comment: @user Matthews answer is better elaborated. Mine was just an example, ment as a starting point.

Comment: @Jack, it's a fair point, but your answer probably has a similar number of comparisons. However, you are caching the output of `stripos()`, so you are saving CPU time there at the expense of increased memory. On huge lists, it would definitely be worth benchmarking the two styles. On small lists, the difference will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a custom sort:

```
<?php
$list = ['Adolf', 'Doe', 'Done'];

function searchFunc($needle)
{
  return function ($a, $b) use ($needle)
  { 
    $a_pos = stripos($a, $needle);
    $b_pos = stripos($b, $needle);

    # if needle is found in only one of the two strings, sort by that one
    if ($a_pos === false && $b_pos !== false) return 1;
    if ($a_pos !== false && $b_pos === false) return -1;

    # if the positions differ, sort by the first one
    $diff = $a_pos - $b_pos;
    # alternatively: $diff = ($b_pos === 0) - ($a_pos === 0) 
    if ($diff) return $diff;

    # else sort by natural case
    return strcasecmp($a, $b);

  };
}

usort($list, searchFunc('do'));

var_dump($list);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(3) "Doe"
  [1] =>
  string(4) "Done"
  [2] =>
  string(5) "Adolf"
}
```

Comment: +1. Though OP should be aware that here `Odometer` will be listed before `Abdomen`, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @Roman, I think that's the point of the search. But if not, removing the `$diff` check and `return` would remove that behavior.

Comment: Don't know, I presume it's used by a sort of "autocomplete" feature,  in that case I'd prefer to have all results that `don't begin with $needle` sorted by alphabet.

Comment: @Roman, his example was ambiguous. I agree with your preference though. I think simply changing the code to be `$diff = ($b_pos === 0) - ($a_pos === 0);` would be sufficient if he's expecting the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You could order the strings based on `stripos($str, $search)` so that the ones in the front (`stripos() == 0`) will come up first.

The following code pushes the substring positions of the search string into a separate array and then uses `array_multisort()` to apply the proper ordering to the matches; doing it this way rather than `usort()` avoids having to call `stripos()` many times.

```
$k = array_map(function($v) use ($search) {
    return stripos($v, $search);
}, $matches);

// $k contains all the substring positions of the search string for all matches

array_multisort($k, SORT_NUMERIC, $matches, SORT_STRING);

// $matches is now sorted against the position
```

Comment: This is a clever solution, but it will fail if the list has strings that do not contain `$search`. stripos() will return false, which is equated with 0. (Easily rectified if array map returns a huge number instead of false.)

Comment: @Matthew I'm assuming the matching has already been done using a grep or sth :)

Comment: Of course, ideally that should be done in the same step as the position determination ;-) let me think about that one.

Comment: You're probably right in that the search is a `SELECT ... WHERE name LIKE '%$string%'`, in which case your answer would be sufficient. I was just pointing it out for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

In modern PHP, writing two rules can be done more concisely than in the past.

Order by:

1. Starts with `do` -- false evaluations come before true evaluations
2. Break ties on the first rule by case-insensitively comparing the whole strings

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Stcgc))

```
$array = [
    'Adolf',
    'Doe',
    'adept',
    'Done',
    'dear',
    'adopt',
    'Deer'
];

$startsWith = 'do';

usort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        (stripos($a, $startsWith) !== 0) <=> (stripos($b, $startsWith) !== 0)
        ?: strcasecmp($a, $b)
);
var_export($array);
```

---

More efficiently (because fewer iterated function call are made) than above, I recommend `array_multisort()`.  The final parameter (`$array`) is the variable that is ultimately modified by the function.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/E7knk))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(fn($v) => stripos($v, $startsWith) !== 0, $array),
    $array,
    SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE,
    $array
);
```